How to resolve blinking effect when swipping between the different fragments of my viewpager
I am facing a problem when swipping between the different fragments of my viewPager . Sometimes everything goes well and sometimes there is a blinking effect when swipping from one fragment to another fragment . It seems like when it blinks , the fragment is recreated . How could i solve it ? Here is my viewpager adapter class :
class ViewPagerAdapter(
list: ArrayList<Fragment>,
fm: FragmentManager,
lifecycle: Lifecycle

):FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {
private val fragmentList:ArrayList<Fragment> = list
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
return fragmentList.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentList[position]
}

}
and here is my viewpager fragment :
    class ViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentViewPagerBinding

val args:ViewPagerFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding=FragmentViewPagerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


        val module:String =args.module

        val module_outil_fragment_list=arrayListOf<Fragment>(
            Question1(),
            Question2(),
            Question3(),
            Question4(),
            Question5(),
            FinFragment()
        )

        when(module){
            "outil"->{
                val adapter=ViewPagerAdapter(
                    module_outil_fragment_list,
                    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                    lifecycle
                )
                binding.viewPagerFragment.adapter=adapter


            }
        }



        //

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

}

